# How to stream Docker container logs via the Go SDK

Tags: docker, logging, go, io, stream

I'm writing a tool for some game server software in Go called [sampctl](https://github.com/Southclaws/sampctl) and the primary function is to spin up a Docker container for a server instance and then capture the logs coming out of the container, clean them up a bit and send them to a location of the users choice such as Elasticsearch or an administration panel for later analysis.

I've got everything else working, the only thing I can't seem to get to work is *streaming* logs. I can *get* logs if the application in the container crashes but I want to stream the logs in realtime.

I've tried using a scanner with the `ContainerLogs` returned `ReadCloser` but that just hung at the terminal.

https://github.com/Southclaws/sampctl/blob/9c76b4dd1b3dbb9e18927da10028d5beeb94f728/run_container.go#L64-L67

Does `ContainerLogs` even support streaming? Or will I need to figure out another solution...

Apologies if this is more of a Go question than a Docker question, I wasn't too sure whether or not to post here or on GoLangBridge...

Answer (score 14):

Have you read [the docs?](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/client#Client.ContainerLogs) The stream has metadata embedded, so you can't quite just pipe it to the console.

I have the following code in a monitoring application:

```
    i, err := cli.ContainerLogs(context.Background(), cid, types.ContainerLogsOptions{
        ShowStderr: true,
        ShowStdout: true,
        Timestamps: false,
        Follow:     true,
        Tail:       "40",
    })
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    hdr := make([]byte, 8)
    for {
        _, err := i.Read(hdr)
        if err != nil {
            log.Fatal(err)
        }
        var w io.Writer
        switch hdr[0] {
        case 1:
            w = os.Stdout
        default:
            w = os.Stderr
        }
        count := binary.BigEndian.Uint32(hdr[4:])
        dat := make([]byte, count)
        _, err = i.Read(dat)
        fmt.Fprint(w, string(dat))
    }
```

It streams as long as I keep it running. There is also [this helper package](https://godoc.org/github.com/moby/moby/pkg/stdcopy) to do most of that for you, but in my case I need to handle the messages individually like this for other reasons.

Comment: Ohh I was aimlessly stripping off the metadata and thought I could just read until \n... I'll give it a try, thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately it's just hanging at `i.Read(hdr)` - are there any settings I must put in the container.Config when I create it?

Comment: Side note: If I `docker attach` and `CTRL+C` in another terminal, it suddenly outputs everything... it seems to have just locked up while waiting for output but as soon as the inner app ends, it flushes!

Comment: Well, the docs do not say anything about the metadata... Here, I found an explaination: https://ahmet.im/blog/docker-logs-api-binary-format-explained/

Comment: @FrancescoPasa thanks, looks like the go docs have gotten less explicit over the last 3 years.

Answer (score 7):

Okay, I managed to resolve this and I'm not sure why captncraig's answer didn't work which I'm still curious about but hey, here's my solution:

I had to set some other options in my `ContainerCreate` call:

```
        Tty:          true,
        AttachStdout: true,
        AttachStderr: true,
```

Then the `scanner.Scan()` method worked perfectly!

Here is the updated code: https://github.com/Southclaws/sampctl/blob/1ad7971d817031bd5a5b3acfad3bf2ea69232c98/run_container.go#L56-L70

Comment: what worked for me was having the `Follow` option in container logs function